# Total likes on all posts of a user

Tags: python, django

How can I count the total likes on all the posts of a particular user in django ?
I have added the html and views.py also. I would like to display the count of total likes below the the total count of posts in html. Thanks

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    slug =models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, default=uuid.uuid1)
    likes =models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: `User.post_likes.count()`

Comment: @BearBrown: I think this will return the number of likes that user has *given*, not received, since it is a m2m on `Post`s.

Comment: yes may be i wrong in understand the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Counting the likes of the posts *written* by a user

You can use an `.aggregate(..)`, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

def total_likes_received(user):
    return user.posts.aggregate(total_likes=Count('likes'))['total_likes'] or 0
```

So we here use the `posts` related object manager of that `user`, and we perform an aggregate, where we count the number of likes of the set of `Post`s, and we attach that to the `total_likes` key.

We then unwrap the value from that key with `...['total_likes']`, but there can still be a problem here. If a user has no posts, or no liked posts, then the value is not `0`, but `None`. We probably do not want that, and that is why we add `or 0` at the end.

## Counting the total number of likes *given* by a user

If you however want to count the number of likes *given* by a certain user (so to posts that are *not* per se written by that user), then you can use:

```
def total_likes_given(user):
    return user.post_likes.count()
```

## Encapsulating it in a `ListView`

We can annotate every post with a `total_likes` attribute, like:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return (Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
                    .order_by('-published_date')
                    .annotate(author_total_likes=Count('author__post__likes'))
               )
```

We can then access the total likes of the author of a post by `{{ post.author_total_likes }}`.

Comment: how to display it in html ?

Comment: @user: you add them to the context you want to render with the template.

Comment: {{ total_likes }} in  html ?

Comment: @user: no. In your view, you need to add an entry that maps the string `'total_likes'` on the outcome of the function call.

Comment: @user: see for example here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something

Comment: Not working. I have added the html and views.py
Can you please suggest the correct way of doing it ? Also, is it possible to do it like the way I have counted posts ?

Comment: @user: see update, your current template however contains a queryset. This is typically not a good idea to do at the template layer.